# Como pegar a posição de um usuário individualmente em um rank, se no banco de dados só possuo a sua pontuação?

Tags: php, mysql

Com o código abaixo eu consigo exibir todos os usuários, pois coloco `DESC` e a variável `$num` e vai incrementando a colocação com `$num++;`.

Mas e se eu quiser pegar a colocação/*rank* do cara que estiver logado `($_SESSION)` e não a de todos?

```
<?php

include "../banco_de_dados/banco_cadastro.php"; 

$sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rank ORDER BY pontuacao DESC");

echo "<table>";
echo"<th > Colocação  </th> <th> Nome </th>  <th > Pontuação </th> ";

$num=1;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) 
{
echo "<tr>";
echo"<td >" . $num . "º</td>"; 
echo "<td  > " .$row['nome'] . "</td>"; 
echo "<td > " .$row['pontuacao']. "</td>";
echo"</tr>";

$num++;
}

echo "</table>"; ?> </div>
```

Comment: A melhor forma era mesmo teres uma coluna com o *ranking* de cada um.

Comment: Quais são as colunas da tua tabela rank?

Comment: Eu sei, no entanto conforme os usuários forem utilizando a aplicação o rank vai sendo alterado, então não posso determinar uma posição para eles.

Comment: As colunas são: NOME para identificar, EMAIL para saber quem está logado e PONTUACAO onde o número tanto pode aumentar quanto diminuir. Também criei o campo  COLOCACAO, mas não sei como colocar dados nele de acordo com a pontuação.

Comment: `ORDER BY pontuacao DESC`? Ai é só fazer uma busca binária no vetor ordenado. A posição no vetor vai ser a posição no ranking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### A query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)+1 FROM rank WHERE pontuacao>(SELECT pontuacao FROM rank WHERE email = '$email' )
```

Usando no *PHP*:

```
$email = (EMAIL DO USUARIO LOGADO); // Sanitize para evitar SQL Injection.
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 AS colocacao FROM rank
          WHERE pontuacao > ( SELECT pontuacao FROM rank WHERE email = '$email' ) ";
sql = mysql_query($query);
...
```

### Explicação:

1. A subquery `(SELECT pontuacao FROM rank WHERE email='$email')` retorna os pontos do usuário logado. Adapte a comparação para o seu caso específico.
2. A query `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rank WHERE pontuacao > ( ... )` conta quantas pessoas tem pontuação igual ou superior ao do usuário logado. Caso prefira, pode trocar o `>` por `>=`, e o `COUNT(*)+1` por `COUNT(*)`. Aí vai depender do seu critério de desempate.
3. Caso queira que empates contem como sendo da mesma colocação, uma saída é trocar o `COUNT(*) + 1` por `COUNT(DISTINCT Pontuacao) + 1` nesta mesma query, mantendo o resto igual.
   (Este ítem 3 foi inspirado na idéia do @ramaral)

> Sugestão: troque o `mysql` por `mysqli_` com *binding*. **[Clique aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/)** para entender melhor.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado, não só solucionou meu problema como me deu uma luz sobre como usar o COUNT. Quanto ao sql injection, vou pegar o email da sessão, então a validação é algo que já está lá atrás. E sim, já li sobre o mysqli e assim que eu estiver estruturado as coisas vou substituir os "mysql". Grato mais uma vez.

Answer (score 5):

Uma solução fazendo 2 *query´s* e uma subtração.

Primeiro calcular o número de Pontuações distintas:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Pontuacao) FROM rank;
```

Depois ver quantos têm menos Pontuação do que o utilizador:

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT Pontuacao) FROM rank
WHERE Pontuacao < (SELECT Pontuacao FROM rank WHERE email = EmailDoUtilizador);
```

Subtrair o segundo do primeiro para obter o *ranking*.

Note que ao utilizar DISTINCT garanto que utilizadores com a mesma pontuação têm o mesmo *ranking*

Comment: Entendi a lógica. Mas como faço a subtração? Fiz a primeira consulta com $xery e a segunda com $query, fica assim $colocacao= ($xery - $query); ?

Comment: Use a resposta do Bacco, pois é a mais correcta. A minha resposta é um exemplo de como, às vezes, conseguimos complicar aquilo que é simples. Como é fácil de entender, subtrair à quantidade total de Pontuações a quantidade de Pontuações menores do que a do utilizador, é o mesmo que contar o total de Pontuações maiores do que a do utilizador, que é o que o Bacco está a propor.

Comment: Eu entendi a lógica das duas e agradeço, pois vocês me ajudaram a entender o COUNT com dois exemplos diferentes. Consegui mostrar na tela o resultado.