# Mostrar ao usuário qual a posição dele nos testes

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma tabela onde armazena as notas dos testes. Ex.:

**Nome, Nota1, Nota2, Nota3, Curso**

O resultado é esse:

```
Nome  | Nota1 | Nota2 | Nota3 | Curso
Pedro | 7.6   | 5.5   | 3.2   | Desenho
João  | 8.0   | 3.1   | 6.6   | Desenho
Ana   | 9.0   | 6.5   | 2.2   | Desenho
```

Gostaria de verificar que a Ana tirou em primeiro lugar, o João em segundo e Pedro em terceiro na coluna Nota1 do curso de Desenho. Dessa forma:

```
Curso Desenho
1º lugar Ana
2º lugar João
3º lugar Pedro
```

Entendo que se eu usar dessa forma:

```
SELECT *, GREATEST(Nota1, Nota2, Nota3) AS MaiorNota FROM curso = '".$curso."' ORDER BY Nota1 DESC;
```

Ou

```
 SELECT * FROM curso = '".$curso."' ORDER BY Nota1 DESC;
```

Consigo pegar a maior nota e colocá-lo em ordem de maior para menor, mas como posso mostrar ao Pedro que ele tirou em 3º lugar, a Ana que ela tirou em 1º e assim por diante?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como pegar a posição de um usuário individualmente em um rank, se no banco de dados só possuo a sua pontuação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14435/como-pegar-a-posi%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-um-usu%c3%a1rio-individualmente-em-um-rank-se-no-banco-de-da)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma alternativa é criar uma coluna dinâmica com a posição de cada aluno dentro da ordenação e, posteriormente, selecioná-lo.

Considerando uma tabela simplificada:

```
create table notas(
  id int not null auto_increment,
  nome varchar(255) not null,
  nota int,
  primary key (id)
);
```

Você poderia fazer:

```
set @pos := 0;

select * from (
  select *, (@pos := @pos+1) as "posição"
  from notas
  order by nota desc
) as ranking
where ranking.nome = 'pedro'
```

Assim, o `select` interno classificará todos os alunos, gerando a coluna `posição`. Depois você faz a seleção a partir deste resultado filtrando pelo nome desejado. O resultado seria algo como:

```
id  nome    nota    posição
1   pedro   76      2
```

Isso considerando os meus dados de testes:

```
insert into notas values (default, 'pedro', 76), 
                         (default, 'joão',  60), 
                         (default, 'ana',   92);
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aeCRDEoDRuqpiK7QwfvpBx/0)</sup>

Comment: Olá Anderson. Fiz exatamente como você informou, trocando claro, as nomenclaturas. A tabela já existia e contém atualmente o total mais de 8 mil registros e o campo de notas está com o valor decimal(7,2). O resultado da  posição  está retornando como 4.283. Só que quando dou uma query  contabilizando a matéria aplicada, ele me retorna apenas 9 alunos que fizeram. No exemplo que você me passou, filtrei a matéria na cláusula WHERE. Ele era para me retornar do 1º ao 9º, certo? Usei também o exemplo aplicado no link que você sugeriu, mas o resultado é o mesmo.

Comment: Tem o link do seu exemplo para eu reproduzir o erro?

Comment: Olá Anderson. Na verdade é uma intranet desenvolvida em PHP e Mysql no cliente.

Comment: Digo o exemplo rodando no db-fiddle, como você diz que fez e retornou errado.

Comment: Ah sim... kkkk ... fiz um teste no DB-Fiddle e funcionou dentro de nossa estrutura. Tentei  colar aqui, mas ultrapassou os caracteres. Vou dar como aceito sua resposta, pois tentei em outra tabela e funcionou tb. Acredito que seja algum problema da tabela que estamos usando ou algo assim. Obrigado pela força!

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você pode fazer assim:
 `select * from nome_tabela WHERE curso='Desenho' ORDER BY Nota1 DESC`

Ou seja o resultado desse select sera em ordem decrescente em relação ao campo Nota1. Você pode utilizar tambem no final dessa query um LIMIT 3 que mostrara apenas os 3 primeiros resultados da tabela, no caso se houver mais registros.
Ficaria assim: `select * from nome_tabela WHERE curso='Desenho' ORDER BY Nota1 DESC LIMIT 3`

Comment: Olá MBoss. Certo. Já tentei dessa forma, mas ele lista as notas de maior para menor. O que preciso é identificar que o Pedro tirou em 3º lugar. O problema é que não limita em até 3º lugar. Ela vai mostrar ao usuário a posição que ele tirou nos testes. Ex.: (5º, 7º, 11º, etc). Eu sabendo pegar a posição do Pedro que usei como exemplo, fica mais fácil de pegar a posição de todos os usuários.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde Fox, vou trazer um outro ponto de vista em questão a sua pergunta, como está marcado a tag PHP vou assumir que você está utilizando o PHP pro processamento/filtragem de dados.

Use o select do **MBoss** *(eu criei um BD teste)*

```
SELECT * FROM tb_nota WHERE curso='desenho' ORDER BY vl_nota DESC
```

E no php, é onde você vai gerar as posições: *(As posições estarão salvas, de acordo com cada aluno)*

```
$query = mysqli_query($connect,"select * from tb_nota WHERE nm_curso='desenho' ORDER BY vl_nota DESC;");
$posicao = 0;
while ($seq = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

    $posicao += 1;

    echo $seq['nm_aluno'] . " Posição : ".$posicao."° <br>";

}
```

**O resultado ficaria assim:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Os dados do banco:** *(Lembrando que estou exibindo com o select feito em DESC)*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero ter ajudado !!